# Using Java Nashorn engine to validate javascript only

Tags: java, validation, syntax, nashorn

Good morning.

I need to run javascript syntax validation through java but I'm struggling to find the best solution.

I did some tests with Nashorn using the following approach:

```
try
{
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    Object retVal = engine.eval("findFieldValue(field);");
}
catch (ScriptException e)
{
    response.put("status", "parseexception");
    response.put("msg", e.getMessage());
}
```

Nashorn throws an exception saying both **findFieldValue** and **field** are undefined, which is correct.
I don't need this kind of validation. All I need is to validate the syntax, like it's done by Esprima JS API

http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

My question is. Can I ignore semantic validation with Nashorn, validating syntax only?

Thank you!

Comment: wrap it in an function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `eval()` which, as you can probably guess, attempts to *evaluate* the expression.

The `NashornScriptEngine` implements `javax.script.Compilable` so it provides a `compile()` method.  To use it you would have to cast `engine` to `NashornScriptEngine`, as in

```
NashornScriptEngine engine = (NashornScriptEngine) new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
```

You get a `ScriptException` if compilation fails.

Comment: No there is not such method. Why is this accepted answer ?

Comment: @kasper Actually, the Nashorn script engine _does_ implement `Compilable`, so it does have a `compile()` method.  I agree this is not obvious in the example provided by the OP, as `engine` would need to be casted to `NashornScriptEngine` to work.  I've updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, that seems true after your answer i also looked into it. We can use something like `compilable = (Compilable) scriptEngine; compilable.compile(script);`. Thanks for update on answer